# WPF User Control's Data Context

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

What are the differences between the following ways of assigning `DataContext` in a `UserControl`?

1. `DataContext = this;`
2. `(Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;`

Answer (score 1):

With `DataContext = this;` also the Content will 'inherit' the same DataContext. So for the Content there is no difference.

But with `(Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;` you will not have a DataContext for the UserControl itself but only for the embedded FrameworkElement.

So if you intent to bind properties of the UserControl (Width, Height, Background) to the DataContext you have to take the first one.